# Using Swift 4, how do I fetch a locally stored image?

Tags: ios, swift

My app is currently storing taken images in a specific naming convention within the app's document directory. I want to show this image in two places, one in my UITableListView and the other in a UIImage view. I have a default image to display if no image was taken.

I'm not certain how I fetch the local image. They are all stored with the format of "BonusName + "_1.jpg", where BonusName matches the row or item I am currently displaying.

Basically, I want something like:

```
if "AR4_1.jpg" is present, display it //(AR4 is the bonus name)
else display "defaultImage" //(defaultImage is already in my Assets)
```

All my googling is finding things like grabbing an array of images from a directory or how to manipulate strings within a local file, both of which are more complex than what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
let documentsUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]) 

let imgUrl =  documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("AR4_1.jpg")

if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:imgUrl.path))
{

    do
    {
         let data = try Data(contentsOf:imgUrl)
         self.imageView.image = UIImage(data:data)

    }
    catch {
       print(error)
    }

}
else
{

     self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"default.jpg")

}
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, except: (a) better to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` (No reason to use NSURL in Swift) (b) `imgPath` is actually an Optional URL, not a path, and (c) it's better to use `Data(contentsOf:)` (In Swift you usually just use the class name, not `Class.init()`.)

Comment: Added it in a hurry for irrelevant reasons , i edited it